# Trying to transition background image after it's loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background of my site when a button is clicked with a smooth transition. I understand this requires a pre-load but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
transition: background-image 3s linear;
```

js

```
document.getElementById("loadBG").onclick = function () {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
  document.getElementById(
    "main"
  ).style.backgroundImage = `url(https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?finland?sig=${randomInt})`;
};
```

Comment: I don't think I was specific enough about the question. I'm trying to pre-load the image for the purpose of a smooth transition when the button is pressed. In my CSS i have 
  transition: background-image 3s linear;

Comment: The `setTimeout` callback will only run after the 3s delay, so you'll still end up with the same problem (because the image is still only being fetched and loaded after 3 seconds). Rather load the image in initially then handle the reveal with a class change on the element - you'll need to get creative with this, maybe overlay the image container on the initial image container and fade in the new one (above the old one) after the time delay.

Answer (score 1):

The `background-image` property you are trying to apply is invalid.
Similarly the `nextImage.src` source attribute you are trying to apply is invalid as well.

**See the code snippet comments for details.**

You don't need to create an image node if all you're doing is applying a `background-image` property.
The `Math.random()` method can be optimised too (not essential, just a nitpick).

The original code (with console.log feedback) and a working version have been included in the code snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById("loadBG-error").onclick = function() {
  const nextImage = new Image();
  nextImage.src = `url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?finland?sig=${Math.random()}")`;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = nextImage.src;
  }, 3000);
  console.log('incorrect background-image property url:',nextImage.src);
};
/*
This happens because the image node's (nextImage) src attribute is being 
declared with a background-image css property, it starts with "url(... )", 
when you have a filepath that doesn't start with a protocol (https://) 
the browser will assume it's relative and prepend the current site's domain 
to the url, e.g: "https://stacksnippets.net/url(...)".
In addition, the double apostrophes in that string are being ASCII encoded to "%22".
*/

document.getElementById("loadBG-fix").onclick = function() {
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = `url(https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?finland?sig=${randomInt})`;
  }, 500);
};
/*
If you just need to declare a background-image property for an existing element, 
there is no need to create an image node first.

The Math.random() method can be further improved to return a set range(1) 
with no floating point value (decimal)(2)
(1) Math.random() * (max - min) + min
(2) Math.floor()
*/
```

```css
#main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<button id="loadBG-error">Load BG (see error)</button>
<hr>
<button id="loadBG-fix">Load BG (apply fix)</button>
```

Comment: It works, the only problem is the background flickers between transitions which is what I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: That changes the scope of your initial problem but I've left you a suggestion to consider in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I had 2 separate problems without realising

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the image as a backgorund image, the container in which it is located must have a specific height and width. I set a height and width for the # main div.

And you don't need definitions like new image(If you have no other purpose with using new Image) because the **src** in the img and background **url**  image  are different from each other. You can't even those two. Because they work differently.

```js
document.getElementById("loadBG").onclick = function() {
  let url = `url("https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?finland?sig=${Math.random()}")`;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = url;
    console.log("work")
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
#main {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;      
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="loadBG">Click me</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```